# Array deletion giving EXC_BAD_ACCESS error

Tags: c++, arrays, delete-operator

I have a class `Foo` defined like this:

```
class Foo
{
  public:
    Foo(int num);
    Foo(const Foo& other);
    ~Foo();

    Foo& operator=(const Foo& other);
    ...

  private:
    string *fooArray;
    void clearMemory();
    ...
}

Foo::Foo(int num)
{
    fooArray = new string[num];
}

Foo::Foo(const Foo& other)
{
    *this = other;
}

Foo::~Foo()
{
    clearMemory();
}

Foo& operator=(const Foo& other)
{
    clearMemory();
    fooArray = new string[other.size]; // size is a private variable
    memcpy(fooArray, other.fooArray, other.size * sizeof(string));
}

void Foo::someOtherFooFuncion(int newNum)
{
    clearMemory(); // crash with Visual Studio, does not crash with g++, but g++ also
                   // crashes when destructor is called
    fooArray = new string[newNum];
}

void Foo::clearMemory()
{
    if(fooArray != NULL)
    {
        delete[] fooArray; // sometimes it crashes here with g++; it always crashes when
                           // compiling in Visual Studio
        fooArray = NULL;
    }
}
```

As noted in the code comments, it is giving me crashes at times. I have tried following the steps in GDB, I got as far as

```
destructing Foo:
@0x7fff5fbff9b0
$26 = {
  fooArray = 0x1001009d8, 
  ...
}
```

And then `delete[] fooArray` is reached, and all of a sudden

```
Foo(49858) malloc: *** error for object 0x100100990: pointer being freed was not allocated
```

Have no idea where the 0x100100990 came from.

I realize the code is very incomplete, but I really don't know even where to start hunting for the bug right now, and would like some tips as to what possible conditions could cause `delete[]` errors.

**EDIT**:

Added c'tor, d'tor, and assignment operator. I am away from PC so code may not be 100% accurate. Assigning values to fooArray and accessing them works just fine though.

Also, I would greatly appreciate a general list of problems that could potentially cause `delete[]` to throw an error, so that I could at least have some idea of where to look in the code.

**EDIT 2**:

So I followed Xeo's advice to use `std::uninitialized_copy`, now the code works fine and compiles under g++. The destructor works fine in Visual Studio as well, but somehow deleting fooArray in `someOtherFooFuncion` makes it crash.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Do you have a default constructor? If so, could you post it.

Comment: Have you remembered the [Rule of Three](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722)? And why aren't you using `std::vector`?

Comment: @MikeSeymour I do have a ctor and assignment operator and dtor, but can't use vector because it is a class assignment

Comment: This code is so wrong on so many levels.. really, scrap the class assignment and use std::vector, please... or atleast scrap memcpy.. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Do not use memcpy in C++

I can't stress that point enough. When `memcpy`ing a class object in C++ (non-POD to be exact), you're breaking that class' *invariants* defined by its constructors, since you are circumventing exactly those. Every time you `memcpy`a a `std::string` class, you get a new object referring to the *same memory* as another object. You'll get a double delete with this, which is causing your crash.

Use `std::uninitialized_copy` from `<algorithm>` like this:

```
//                      src_begin             src_end           dest
std::uninitialized_copy(other.array, other.array + other.size, array);
```

(untested because I'm writing this from my iPod)

Or even better, just use `std::vector` instead of raw memory. You'll have no need for a destructor and copy ctor / assignment operator anymore.

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for the answer! I'll try it out soon. Unfortunately, as much as I would like to use vectors, this is a class assignment that explicitly requires a dynamic array :(

Comment: It worked! In g++ at least. Visual Studio still crashes when I try to run my code though :(

Comment: @wrongusername: Without more code, it's going to be hard to find out what exactly goes wrong. Please create an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org), so we can investigate further.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you define a copy constructor and an assignment operator. They will need to *allocate memory* for `fooArray`. If you don't define the copy ctor and `operator=`, the compiler will generate them for you. However, the compiler-generated ones will just copy the `fooArray` pointer, potentially resulting in double `deletes`.

If you are defining them already, please add the relevant code to your question.

**edit:** I can see that your copy constructor is not allocating memory, and your assignment operator is using `memcpy()`. Both can cause problems.

Comment: I have already defined the copy constructor and assignment operator, and they seem to work find, since I write to them in memory. I will add the code soon.

Answer (score 1):

If you define a default constructor you must initialise `fooArray` to NULL, otherwise `fooArray` could be pointing to a random memory location which is then subject to a `delete[]`.

Comment: hm I initialize a dynamic array instead of NULL, figured it would work just as well